# Sonarqube security reports : OWASP Top 10

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube, devops

Is it possible to keep a security report OWASP Top 10 after every scan, so i can identify the delta of OWASP vulnerabilities between two version ?

Sonarqube GUI offer the security reports just for the last scan

[image]

Thanks for any advice

Comment: Which sonaqube version your're using ?

Comment: I do not even find the menu "Security Reports" on Sonarqube 7.9. I badly need this OWASP Top 10 report. Can you tell me what I am missing!!

Comment: You need to add the sonar-xanitizer-plugin-X.X.X.jar to your sonarqube-X.X/extensions/plugins folder

Comment: @FuSsA Is this something like now this menu is not supporting in-built without adding the mentioned plugin? And this plugin's latest release supports only SonarQube 7.3. Please tell me what way I can achieve security report( OWASP Top 10 -a1 to a10).

Comment: Hi @FuSsA I have added this plugin. but Still, I am not able to find the menu "Security Reports'. I have restarted SnarQube also.

Comment: Hi @DarshanaPatel, checkout those link https://update.sonarsource.org/plugins/compatibility-matrix.html & https://github.com/RIGS-IT/sonar-xanitizer , i'm using it with sonarqube 7.7

Comment: @FuSsA I was able to scan code with those security rules but i was not able to see the reports.direct for Owasp 10. And this is not working because I have a sonarQube community edition which does not support the feature for that report. Now we can see the "Security Report" only in EE or DCE. See this - https://www.google.com/url?q=https://www.sonarqube.org/sonarqube-7-9-lts/&sa=D&source=hangouts&ust=1567139210724000&usg=AFQjCNFxvUu_LqwxW3iHHC2y02wj-R8dvQ

Comment: I'm using a community Edition too .. V 7.7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to achieve my goal by using the web api after each scan, like example below :

```
http://0.0.0.0:9099/api/issues/search?componentKeys=com.test&facets=owaspTop10&owaspTop10=a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8,a9,a10
```